# How to Access wireless router admin page when its ip is public ip given by the isp?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a dlink router. and my laptop connects to it via wifi
but when i type in CMD ipconfig to find the default gateway which must be the router the address looks something like this:

ipv4 address: 49.144.162.175
subnet mask: 255.255.224.0
default gateway: 49.144.160.1

but when i enter the default gateway to my browser i cant access my router admin page?
how can i find the right ip of my router if I have a public IP assigned by the ISP?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running the router in a bridge mode and the gateway is assigned to your machine by the ISP DHCP. If it is a d-link router, the ip address if unchanged from default is 192.168.1.1